# Hamiltonian tends to $+\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert\to\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

I am a bit confused since it is said that
$$
H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}
$$
is a global Lyapunov function and one condition for this is that
$$
H(x,y)\to+\infty\text{ as }\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert\to\infty.
$$
As far as I see this is not fulfilled here.

Comment: Indeed, that condition is not satisfied. I don't think much else can be said, unless you provide more details.

Comment: I guess there is some mistake in the formulation, since the given system is $x'=y,~~y'=x+x^2-y$ and as Hamiltonian, $H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$. This is not the right Hamiltonian for the system, isn't it?

Comment: You should also give the symplectic form. With the standard one (the matrix $J=\begin{bmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 & \end{bmatrix}$), that Hamiltonian is ok.

Comment: What do you mean with symplectic form?

Comment: If you have never heard this term before, then nevermind. That Hamiltonian is surely ok.